# Can't connect to vsftpd server with alpakka (akka-streams)

Tags: ftp, akka, alpakka, vsftpd

I'm trying to recreate the [traversal example](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/ftp.html#traversing-a-remote-ftp-folder-recursively) for the Alpakka FTP-Source connector with a [vsftpd server](https://hub.docker.com/r/fauria/vsftpd) in a Docker image, but can't seem to connect. Any pointers how to adjust the code would be very welcome:

```
FtpSettings ftpSettings = FtpSettings
  .create(InetAddress.getLocalhost())
  .withPort(21)
  .withCredentials(FtpCredentials.NonAnonFtpCredentials.create("news", "test"))
  .withBinary(true)
  .withPassiveMode(true)
  .withConfigureConnectionConsumer(
    (FTPClient ftpClient) -> {
      ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(
        new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));
    });

Source<FtpFile, NotUsed> ftp = Ftp.ls("/", ftpSettings);
ftp.to(Sink.foreach(s -> LOGGER.info(s.name())));
```

FYI: The login information is working e.g. with filezilla.

Comment: Turns out the setup of the container with `PASV_ADDRESS=foo` was the problem. Why Filezilla was able to resolve it is beyond me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Source.to` returns a `RunnableGraph`, which is a 'blueprint' that you still have to 'run':

```scala
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.stream.Materializer;
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer;

// Create the blueprint:
RunnableGraph blueprint = ftp.to(Sink.foreach(s -> LOGGER.info(s.name())));

// Create the system to run the stream in:
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

// Run the stream:
blueprint.run(materializer);
```

You can also use the 'runWith' shorthand:

```
ftp.runWith(Sink.foreach(s -> LOGGER.info(s.name())), materializer);
```

Comment: Yup, was being a blockhead... Now I just need to figure out why this resolves to a `500 OOPS: invalid pasv_address`, when both filezilla and firefox are able to resolve it